# c++ va_arg typecast issue

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

All,

I am writing a small c++ app and have been stumped by this issue. Is there a way to create (and later catch ) the error while accessing element from va_list macro using va_arg if element type is not expected. Eg:-

```
count=va_arg(argp,int); 
if (count <= 0 || count > 30)
{   
      reportParamError();   return;
}
```

Now, if I am passing a typedef instead of int, I get garbage value on MS compiler but 95% of time count gets value 0 on gcc (on 64 bit sles10 sys). Is there a way I can enforce some typechecking, so that I get an error that can be caught in a catch block?

Any ideas on this would be very helpful to me. Or is there a better way to do this. The function prototype is:-

```
 void process(App_Context * pActx, ...)
```

The function is called as

```
 process(pAtctx,3,type1,type2,type3);
```

It is essential for pActx to be passed as 1st parameter and hence cannot pass count as 1st parameter.

---

Update-1

Ok, this sounds strange but nargs does not seem to part of va_list on sles10 gcc. I had to put in

```
#ifdef _WIN32
tempCount=va_arg(argp,int)
#endif
```

After using this, parameters following nargs do not get garbage values. However, this introduces compiler/platform based #ifdefs....Thanks Chris and Kristopher

Comment: Why not make the count the 2nd parameter? `void process(App_Context *pActx, std::size_t nargs, ...);`

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your suggestion. I had gone with that option, but with gcc , the 1st paramter (type1) after nargs is getting garbage value. The last parameter also gets garbage value. I assume that nargs is also part of va_list in sense va_start(argp,App_Context *) followed by va_arg(argp,int).

Answer (score 5):

If you know a count will always be passed as the second argument, then you could always change the signature to this:

```
void process(App_Context * pActx, int count, ...)
```

If that's not an option, then there is really no way to catch it.  That's just how the variable-argument-list stuff works: there is no way for the callee to know what arguments are being passed, other than whatever information the caller passes.

If you look into how the `va_arg` macro and related macros are implemented, you may be able to figure out how to inspect all the stuff on the stack.  However, this would not be portable, and it is not recommended except as a debugging aid.

You also might want to look into alternatives to variable-arguments, like function overloading, templates, or passing a `vector` or `list` of arguments.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. I had tried the approach you mentioned. I faced an issue with this approach. The first argument after count always got garbage value on 64 bit sles10 system. The va_list comes from a .c file. After some basic checks, the va_list is passed to a .cpp file. Thats where the garbage issue comes into picture. In the .c function , I did va_start(argp,App_Context *). count=va_arg(argp,int). Then I call process(pActx,count,argp). Inside it va_arg(argp, type1). Because type1 always got garbage value, I had to change the approach.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. varargs doesn't provide any way to check the types of parameters passed in. You must only read them with the correct type which means that you need another way of communicating type information.

You are likely to be better off avoiding varargs functionality unless you really need it. It's only really a C++ feature for the sake of legacy functions such as `printf` and friends.

Comment: +1 the fundamental problem here is that `main` is type-unsafe as defined by the standard.